# dispatch is not defined inside async action creators

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to dispatch another action inside one async action creator. However, when I am using dispatch function provided by redux-thunk middleware, it is throwing `Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function` error.

Below are the files for more help

**store/store.dev.js**

```
use strict';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {
const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
  console.log('store returned', store);
return store;
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import configureStore from './store';
import App from './containers/App.js';
import routes from './routes/index.js';

hydrate(
  <Provider store={configureStore()}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      {renderRoutes(routes)}
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**reducer**

```
'use strict';

import { LOGIN_SUBMITTED, LOGIN_COMPLETED } from '../constants/ActionTypes.js';

const loginSubmitReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  console.log('in reducer');
    switch (action.type) {

      case LOGIN_SUBMITTED:
      console.log('login submitted case');
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          loginSubmitted: true
        });

      case LOGIN_COMPLETED:
      console.log('login completed case');
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          loginCompleted: true
        });

      default:
      console.log('in default case');
        return {
          a:1
        };
    }
}

export default loginSubmitReducer;
```

**containers/App.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { loginCompleted, loginSubmitted } from '../actions';
import { createStructuredSelector, createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Header, ButtonDemo, LoginForm } from '../components';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      appState: {
        entry: 'yes'
      }
    }

    console.log('props in App constructor', props);
    console.log('context in App constructor', context);

    this.newFunc = this.newFunc.bind(this);
  }
  newFunc () {
    console.log('props', this.props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log('props in main App', this.props);
    console.log('Actions', this.props.actions);
    console.log('context in App', this.context);
    // this.props.actions.loginCompleted();
    const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
      lightBaseTheme
    });

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <LoginForm 
              appstate = {this.props.appState}
              dispatchAction = {this.props.actions}
            />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

// const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({});
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { appState: state.loginSubmitReducer };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({ loginCompleted, loginSubmitted }, dispatch)
  };
  // dispatch(loginCompleted());
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**components**

```
    'use strict';

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import { loginAction } from '../actions';
// import '../css/style.css';


class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.loginSubmit = this.loginSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    loginSubmit() {
        console.log('Login fomr submitted', this.props);
        console.log('loginAction', loginAction);
        loginAction()();
    }

    render () {
        console.log('props when login rendered', this.props);
        return (
            <div className="loginForm">
                <div className="title">LOGIN</div>
                <form>
                    <TextField 
                        hintText="Username"
                        floatingLabelText="Username"/><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Password"
                        type="Password"
                        floatingLabelText="Password"/><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Login" 
                        secondary={true} 
                        onClick={this.loginSubmit}
                        className="submitBtn" /><br/>
                    <br/>
                    <FloatingActionButton                       
                        secondary={true}
                        className="registerBtn">
                        <ContentAdd />                      
                    </FloatingActionButton>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**actions/loginAction.js**

```
'use strict';

// import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise';
// require('es6-promise').polyfill();
// require('isomorphic-fetch');
import request from 'superagent';
// import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import loginCompleted from './loginCompletedAction.js';
import loginSubmitted from './loginSubmittedAction.js';

const loginAction = (dispatch) => {
    console.log('validateUserLogin executed', this);
    console.log('validateUserLogin dispatch', dispatch);
    return (dispatch) => {
        // console.log('first return', dispatch);
        // this.props.dispatch(loginSubmitted());
        // this.props.dispatchAction.loginSubmitted();
        dispatch(loginSubmitted());

        request.get('http://localhost:3000/loginSubmit')
            .end((err, res) => {
                console.log('res', res);
                console.log('err', err);
                // this.props.dispatchAction.loginCompleted();
            });
    }
}

export default loginAction;
```

**Folder structure**

[image: Project structure]

I am using `redux-thunk` middleware that exposes dispatch function to async action creators. Still it doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Is this the line that is causing the error? `loginAction()();` I think you need to get `loginAction` from props (populated by `mapDispatchToProps())` instead of importing it in your component. When you import it directly, it doesn't get wrapped, so `dispatch()` is not passed into it. If it's not that line, please tell us which line causes the error! That's pretty important info.

Comment: @skypecakes -- `dispatch(loginSubmitted());` in `actions/loginAction.js` is causing the error.

Comment: Okay, but is that called from loginAction()? If it is, you're clearly not passing in `dispatch`, but it's expecting you to.

Comment: @skypecakes-- Yes.. I am not passing. Let me check.

Comment: loginAction will work if you `dispatch(loginAction())`, and make the change suggested by @Sag1v. Usual way to do that is in `mapDispatchToProps`. Otherwise `dispatch` will not be defined. You may find it helpful to study how `dispatch` is passed around - it seems mysterious with all the arrow functions (well, it did to me) but there's a clear path.

Comment: You are right. It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Your first argument of the action creator should not be the `dispatch` but the argument you pass to the action creator.

```
const loginAction = () => (dispatch) => {
    console.log('validateUserLogin executed', this);
    console.log('validateUserLogin dispatch', dispatch);
    // console.log('first return', dispatch);
    // this.props.dispatch(loginSubmitted());
    // this.props.dispatchAction.loginSubmitted();
    dispatch(loginSubmitted());

    request.get('http://localhost:3000/loginSubmit')
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log('res', res);
            console.log('err', err);
            // this.props.dispatchAction.loginCompleted();
        });
}
```

**Edit**
As a follow up to your comment, iat first i thought you are not implementing the `redux-thunk` properly as a middle-ware but according to your code it looks ok.
Then I've noticed that you are not really dispatching `loginAction` but just invoking it.
You should dispatch it `dispatch(loginAction())`. Your component should be connected to `redux` then you will have access to `dispatch`.

Comment: That did not make any difference. I have removed the dispatch argument and still it is throwing the same error. @Sag1v

Comment: look at the full example, is this how your action creator looks like?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. I removed the argument from action